# CSS div flip works first time only

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div to flip whenever I click a button. With every click front and back should toggle. It works for the first click only.

[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uo2napq8/).

**html:**

```
<div style="margin-left:100px;padding-top:100px;">
    <div class="vertical flip-container">
        <div class="flipper" id='flipper'>
            <div class="front">
                Front Side
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                Back Side
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('flipper').style.transform = 'rotateX(-180deg)'">Tap the button</button>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 400px;
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 220px;
    height: 280px;
}

.back {
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color:red;
    animation: toBack 0.3s linear normal forwards;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    background-color:green; 
    animation: toFront 0.3s linear normal forwards;
}
.vertical.flip-container {
    position: relative;
}

@keyframes toBack {  
  0% {z-index:0;}
  100% {z-index:1;}
}
@keyframes toFront {
  0% {z-index:1;}
  100% {z-index:0;}
}
.vertical.flip-container .flipper {
    transform-origin: 100% 100px; /* half of height */
}
```

I am new to css3. Please help me  find the issue.

Comment: You only ever set it to `-180` (after the first click), once it's at `-180`, it won't move any more. You need it to add another 180 degrees each time, or do `-180` the first time, and `0` the second, etc.. etc..

Comment: In addition to the above comment, it is better to use a CSS class for the transform and toggle it on and off at every button press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with jQuery

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#rotate").click(
        function () {
            $("#flipper").toggleClass("back");
        }            
    );
});
```

**HTML** (I only added an ID to your button)

```
<div style="margin-left:100px;padding-top:100px;">
   <div class="vertical flip-container">
       <div class="flipper" id='flipper'>
           <div class="front">Front Side</div>
       <div class="back">Back Side</div>
   </div>
</div>
<button id="rotate">Tap the button</button>
```

And here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktoaxpdb/)